# Change page name based on the tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Im having a small app built using jquery mobile and nativedroid2.

I would like to know if its possible to change the page heading name based on the tab name?

For an example http://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/2a7so7r5/1/ You will see the page heading is `Friends` and my active tab is `Friends` so when i move to the next tab. `Work` the page title should change accordingly

Below is my demo JS code

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $("div[role=main]").on("swipeleft", function (event) {
        changeNavTab(true);
    });

    $("div[role=main]").on("swiperight", function (event) {
        changeNavTab(false);
    });
});

function changeNavTab(left) {
    var $tabs = $('ul[data-role="nd2tabs"] li');
    console.log($tabs);
    var len = $tabs.length;
    var curidx = 0;
    $tabs.each(function(idx){
        if ($(this).hasClass("nd2Tabs-active")){
            curidx = idx;
        }
    });

    var nextidx = 0;
    if (left) {
        nextidx = (curidx >= len - 1) ? 0 : curidx + 1;
    } else {
        nextidx = (curidx <= 0) ? len - 1 : curidx - 1;
    }
    $tabs.eq(nextidx).click();

}
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to attach to the click handler of each tab  item.  Just add this block of code to your `$(document)` function.  And set an id for your page heading element.

```
<h1 id="heading" class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay='0.4s'>Friends</h1>

$('ul[data-role="nd2tabs"] li').on('click',function(){
    $("#heading").html($(this).html());
});
```

Here's the updated fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/2a7so7r5/18/

Comment: Thank you :) Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what expected but this is my aproach 
[Modified example](http://jsfiddle.net/2a7so7r5/19/)

```
function changeNavTab(left) {
    var $active = $('ul[data-role="nd2tabs"] li.nd2Tabs-active');
    if(left){
        var $moveto = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('ul[data-role="nd2tabs"] li:first');
    }else{
        var $moveto = $active.prev().length ? $active.prev() : $('ul[data-role="nd2tabs"] li:last');
    }
    var title = $moveto.text();
    $("h1.ui-title").text(title);
}
```